# Database value cannot get it to the Dropdownlist jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

In my database there's a column, name is `Sequence` & it consist of numbers(int). In my application's edit function I need to show that selected number in my jQuery dropdown list.

In my AJAX call I sent ProductId and get the specific row.

Html Control

```
 <select class="form-control" id="drpsequence"></select>
```

My jQuery dropdown

```
 $("#drpsequence option:selected").append($("<option></option>").val(msg._prodlng[0].Sequence).text(msg._prodlng[0].Sequence));
```

In the above code `msg._prodlng[0].Sequence` comes as selected number

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do but it looks like you are adding an `<option>` tag into another `<option>` tag which is most likely not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If the returned value already exists as a selected option:

```
$("#drpsequence").val(msg._prodlng[0].Sequence).prop('selected', true);
```

Or, if you need to add an option:

```
var opt = $("<option>")
   .val(msg._prodlng[0].Sequence)
   .text(msg._prodlng[0].Sequence);

$("#drpsequence").append(opt);
```

**Snippet example:**

```js
// foo --> select
$('#foo').val('baz').prop('selected', true);

$('#bim').click(function(){
    $('#foo').append('<option id="boop" value="boop">boop</option>'); //<-- or loaded value
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="foo">
    <option>-- select --</option>
    <option id="bar" value="bar">bar</option>
    <option id="baz" value="baz">baz</option>
</select>
<button id="bim">Add an option</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do one of following.

- Either find that option and make that `selected = true` like this.

```js
$("#sel option").each(function(i) {
  if ($(this).val() == "Orange") $(this).attr("selected", "true");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
</select>
```

- Or if that option is not found then add and make that `selected = true`.

Like the one, which you had in your question.